# Preventing an animation from looping

Tags: createjs

I want my animation to only play once and not loop. My understanding is that you can do that by setting "next" to false. However, my animation is still looping. Here is my sprite sheet json file:

```
{

    "images": [
        "ressources/atlas/apparition.png"
    ],

    "framerate": 12,

    "frames": [
        [1, 1, 170, 172, 0, -15, -15],
        [1, 175, 164, 165, 0, -19, -18],
        [1, 342, 156, 160, 0, -23, -21],
        [159, 342, 147, 146, 0, -27, -28],
        [167, 175, 134, 128, 0, -33, -37],
        [173, 1, 122, 96, 0, -40, -52],
        [173, 99, 96, 64, 0, -52, -68]
    ],

    "animations": {
      "apparition": { "frames": [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], "next": false }
    }

}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well... it seems that you must use `gotoAndPlay()` if you want to prevent looping. I was using `play()`.

Comment: With gotoAndPlay() it keeps looping for me. and play() does nothing for me.